# What is the scope of using SQL Server's "set transaction isolation level read uncommitted"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to ask about using the

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

in SQL Server 2008.

I have a system in Winforms that gets some data from the DB with select queries.

When I use this statement in a select query from my C# code does it affect other select queries that will run after? Should I reset this statement somehow, and if so, how do I reset it ? Should I use

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

after each query in which I used the READ UNCOMMITTED statement ?

I want this statement to be relevant only to a specific queries that I need.

Comment: from the easily found msdn page: "Controls the locking and row versioning behavior of Transact-SQL statements issued by a connection to SQL Server." the scope is the current connection. connections on threads from a thread pool may be problematic.

Comment: So do I have a way of controling it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) that are related to scopes:

- Only one of the isolation level options can be set at a time, and it remains set for **that connection** until it is explicitly changed.
- If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a **stored procedure or trigger**, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset to the level in effect when the object was invoked.
- **User-defined functions** and **common language runtime (CLR) user-defined types** cannot execute SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL.

So Yes. it will "affect other select queries that will run after". You should change the ISOLATION LEVEL back or use [table hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) just for that particular query:

```
SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
```